# unable to convert byte array of Unicode16 data to char array

Tags: string, windows, file, winapi

I try to read a INF file in Windows, which is encoded typically in Unicode-16 .
I copy the contents to a byte array. But unable to convert it to a string using wcstomb_s or sprintf.
wcstomb_s returns error no. 42, "illegal byte sequence"

I don't get where I am going wrong. Can you guys help me out?

```
void main()
{
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER fileSize = { 0 };
    SIZE_T bufLen = 0;
    PBYTE  pReadBuffer = NULL;
    PCHAR  pAsciiBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    BOOLEAN bRes = FALSE;
    SIZE_T   bytesConverted = 0;
    hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\Windows\\INF\\oem100.inf", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &fileSize);

    bufLen = fileSize.QuadPart;

    pReadBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(bufLen + sizeof(WCHAR));
    ZeroMemory(pReadBuffer, bufLen);

    bRes = ReadFile(hFile, pReadBuffer, (DWORD)(bufLen), &dwBytesRead, NULL);

    pReadBuffer[bufLen] = L'\0';
    pAsciiBuffer = (PCHAR) malloc(bufLen + sizeof(CHAR));
    ZeroMemory(pAsciiBuffer, bufLen);

    INT err = wcstombs_s(&bytesConverted, pAsciiBuffer, bufLen, (PWCHAR)pReadBuffer, bufLen);

    //sprintf_s(pAsciiBuffer, bufLen, "%S", (PWCHAR)pReadBuffer);

    printf("pAscii Buffer:\n %s\n", pAsciiBuffer);
    
    printf("pReadBuffer: %s\n", (PCHAR)pReadBuffer);

    PCHAR errStr = malloc(sizeof(CHAR) * 100);

    strerror_s(errStr, 100, err);


    printf("ERROR:: %s",errStr);

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    free(pReadBuffer);
    free(errStr);
    free(pAsciiBuffer);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: this files typically begin with 2 byte [*BOM (U+FEFF)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), but `wcstombs_s` or `WideCharToMultiByte` not handle this. you need skip *BOM* yourself

Comment: Presumably you are trying to convert the UTF-16 BOM. Start decoding at `pReadBuffer + 2` instead if there is a BOM. Though, really, you should thoroughly investigate whether you should convert (trash) your input data into a less-than-useful character encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mbstowcs_s() to properly convert the byte array to a wide-char string worked.
I could then copy it to an Ascii(char) buffer if needed, or parse it as such.

```
    PWCHAR wcStr = (PWCHAR)malloc(bufLen +sizeof(WCHAR));
    SIZE_T numChars = (bufLen+sizeof(WCHAR)) / sizeof(WCHAR);
    
    ZeroMemory(wcStr, bufLen);
    err = mbstowcs_s(&bytesConverted, wcStr, numChars, (PCHAR) pReadBuffer, numChars-1);
```